# Accessing elements in an sklearn sparse array

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, minimum-spanning-tree

I'm trying to write a function for a euclidean minimum spanning tree, where I have run into trouble is finding K nearest neighbor, as you can see I call the function that returns a sparse array tat contains the the indexes and distance to its nearest neighbor, however I can not access the elements as I assumed I would:

```
 for p1,p2, w in A:
    do things
```

as this returns an error that A only returns 1 item(not 3). Is there a way to access the elements of each within this data set to form edges with the distance as weight? I am pretty new to python and still trying to learn all of finer details of the language.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import kneighbors_graph
from kruskalsalgorithm import *
import networkx as nx


def EMST(inlist):

    graph = nx.Graph()

    for a,b in inlist:
        graph.add_node((a,b))

    print("nodes = ", graph.nodes())

    A = kneighbors_graph(graph.nodes(),1,mode='distance', metric='euclidean',include_self=False,n_jobs=-1)
    A.toarray()
```

This is how I am testing my function

```
mylist = [[2,3],[4,2],[9,4],[3,1]]
EMST(mylist)
```

and my output is:

```
nodes = [(2, 3), (4, 2), (9, 4), (3, 1)]
(0, 1)    2.2360679775
(1, 3)    1.41421356237
(2, 1)    5.38516480713
(3, 1)    1.41421356237
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not really explain what exactly you want to do. There are a lot of potential things imaginable.

But in general you should follow the docs @ [scipy.sparse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html). In your case, sklearn's function guarantees the [csr_format](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix).

One potential usage is something like:

```
from scipy import sparse as sp
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

mat = sp.random(4,4, density=0.4)
print(mat)

I, J, V = sp.find(mat)
print(I)
print(J)
print(V)
```

Output:

```
(3, 0)        0.846310916686
(1, 3)        0.313273516932
(3, 1)        0.524548159573
(2, 0)        0.44345289378
(2, 1)        0.22957721373
(2, 2)        0.534413908947
[2 3 2 3 2 1]
[0 0 1 1 2 3]
[ 0.44345289  0.84631092  0.22957721  0.52454816  0.53441391  0.31327352]
```

Of course you could do:

```
for a, b, w in zip(I, J, V):
    print(a, b, w)
```

which prints:

```
2 0 0.44345289378
3 0 0.846310916686
2 1 0.22957721373
3 1 0.524548159573
2 2 0.534413908947
1 3 0.313273516932
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated my original post to reflect what I am looking for. Im trying to access the elements within sparse array to create edges from their nearest neighbor with the distance as the weight of each edge

Comment: And what's missing? The last example prints out all edges and weights?

Answer (score 1):

I can recreate your display with:

```
In [65]: from scipy import sparse
In [72]: row = np.array([0,1,2,3])
In [73]: col = np.array([1,3,1,1])
In [74]: data = np.array([5,2,29,2])**.5
In [75]: M = sparse.csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(4,4))
In [76]: M
Out[76]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [77]: print(M)
  (0, 1)    2.23606797749979
  (1, 3)    1.4142135623730951
  (2, 1)    5.385164807134504
  (3, 1)    1.4142135623730951
In [78]: M.A   # M.toarray()
Out[78]: 
array([[0.        , 2.23606798, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.41421356],
       [0.        , 5.38516481, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 1.41421356, 0.        , 0.        ]])
```

`pts=[(2, 3), (4, 2), (9, 4), (3, 1)]'.  Distance from`pts[0] to pts[1]`is`sqrt(5)`, etc.

Sparse `coo` format gives access to the coordinates and distances.  `sparse.find` also produces these arrays.

```
In [83]: Mc = M.tocoo()
In [84]: Mc.row
Out[84]: array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
In [85]: Mc.col
Out[85]: array([1, 3, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
In [86]: Mc.data
Out[86]: array([2.23606798, 1.41421356, 5.38516481, 1.41421356])
```

Checking the point and matrix match:

```
In [95]: pts = np.array([(2, 3), (4, 2), (9, 4), (3, 1)])
In [96]: pts
Out[96]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 2],
       [9, 4],
       [3, 1]])
In [97]: for r,c,d in zip(*sparse.find(M)):
    ...:     print(((pts[r]-pts[c])**2).sum()**.5)
    ...:     
2.23606797749979
5.385164807134504
1.4142135623730951
1.4142135623730951
```

Or getting all closest distances at once:

```
In [107]: np.sqrt(((pts[row,:]-pts[col,:])**2).sum(1))
Out[107]: array([2.23606798, 1.41421356, 5.38516481, 1.41421356])
In [110]: np.linalg.norm(pts[row,:]-pts[col,:],axis=1)
Out[110]: array([2.23606798, 1.41421356, 5.38516481, 1.41421356])
```

---

A 'brute force' minimum distance calc:

All pairwise distances:

```
In [112]: dist = np.linalg.norm(pts[None,:,:]-pts[:,None,:],axis=2)
In [113]: dist
Out[113]: 
array([[0.        , 2.23606798, 7.07106781, 2.23606798],
       [2.23606798, 0.        , 5.38516481, 1.41421356],
       [7.07106781, 5.38516481, 0.        , 6.70820393],
       [2.23606798, 1.41421356, 6.70820393, 0.        ]])
```

(compare this with `Out[78]`)

'blank' out the diagonal

```
In [114]: D = dist + np.eye(4)*100
```

Minimum distance and coordinates (by row):

```
In [116]: np.min(D, axis=1)
Out[116]: array([2.23606798, 1.41421356, 5.38516481, 1.41421356])
In [117]: np.argmin(D, axis=1)
Out[117]: array([1, 3, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
```